# How to store the root url of api in angular 4 app?

Tags: angular

I followed the official tutorials and made services for the Apis but absolute url of the Api is hardcoded in services.

I want to keep the base url of Api somewhere so that i can append it to the  url path in each service before call. i also need to change the base url of Api before building (or after building).

i tried to put it in sessionstorage, but that is a bad idea as anyone can change it and my application will start hitting other domain.

so i kept it hard-coded and placed a post-push hook on the git to replace the url after build. but it is more like a hack than a solution.

Can i place a file in the root directory of angular and put Api url in json format . And include it in each service so that i can exclude the file from git and each teammate and the build server can have their own file having different url.

What should be the recommended way of doing it?

Comment: this may helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44622058/how-can-we-use-angular4-environment-variable/44622195#44622195

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the environment files

If youre using the cli you should use the environment files. By configuring the angular-cli.json file you can manage all the available environments and create new ones. For example you could create an environment.dev.js file and store the values there, by making git ignore it any member in your team can have a customized one.

Said environment file will overwrite the original environment.js

See this SO answer [angular-cli for angular2 how to load environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39701389/angular-cli-for-angular2-how-to-load-environment-variables)

Answer (score 29):

After release of Angular 4.3 we have a possibility to use HttpClient interceprtors. 
The advantage of this method is avoiding of import/injection of API_URL is all services with api calls.

This is my basic implementation:

```
@Injectable()
export class ApiUrlInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
constructor(@Inject(API_URL) private apiUrl: string) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    req = req.clone({url: this.prepareUrl(req.url)});
    return next.handle(req);
  }

  private isAbsoluteUrl(url: string): boolean {
    const absolutePattern = /^https?:\/\//i;
    return absolutePattern.test(url);
  }

  private prepareUrl(url: string): string {
    url = this.isAbsoluteUrl(url) ? url : this.apiUrl + '/' + url;
    return url.replace(/([^:]\/)\/+/g, '$1');
  }
}
```

InjectionToken declaration:

```
export const API_URL = new InjectionToken<string>('apiUrl');
```

Provider registration:

```
{provide: API_URL, useValue: environment.apiUrl}
{provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ApiUrlInterceptor, multi: true, deps: [API_URL]}
```

Environment.ts:

```
export const environment = {
 production: false,
 apiUrl: 'some-dev-api'
};
```

Comment: this looks good . even i was searching for HttpClient interceptors but can u elaborate on things like where should the code for "Injection Token declaration" and "Provider registration" be placed

Comment: Not sure about this right now. I`he placed this code in app.module.ts.
I`ll check if this decision is scalable enough  and leave a comment here later.

Comment: Where do you put the Injection Token declaration?

Comment: @redOctober13 I`ve put 
export const API_URL = new InjectionToken<string>('apiUrl');
just before ApiUrlInterceptor declaration

Comment: Provider registration is still in the app.module.file

Comment: Ok, I had it in with the provider registration (I have an interceptors/index.ts file to barrel all my interceptors together). But if I take it out of there, then the provider registration complains about `API_URL` being undefined.

Comment: Why not just have this in the ApiUrlInterceptor: 
`import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
export const API_URL = environment.API_URL`  I still like this explanation, if it would be better to create a new questions so you can answer with this and maybe add file names, I can do that.

Comment: @redOctober13 Yes, you can just import the api url from environment file.
Injection token just serve for your convenience. They give you an opportunity to make your modules configurable. This will be useful, if you develop some sharable module (with this interceptor) between several application (maybe community also), as they can have different api urls.
Injection token helped me to write the unit test also. I made
`{provide: API_URL, useValue: 'http://example.com'}`
in my spec file to make it not dependent from my environment.

Comment: But if you export the `const` in your interceptor file, what do you put in your provider file (e.g. `app.module`) so that API_URL is not undefined?

Comment: @redOctober13 In your barrel file, you import API_URL: 

`import {API_URL, ApiUrlInterceptor} from './api-url.interceptor';`

The "InjectionToken declaration" is in the ApiUrlInterceptor file. And this is what your barrel http interceptor file should look like :

`/** "Barrel" of Http Interceptors */
import ... ;

/** Http interceptor providers in outside-in order */
export const httpInterceptorProviders = [
    {provide: API_URL, useValue: environment.apiUrl},
    {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ApiUrlInterceptor, multi: true, deps: [environment.apiUrl]},
];`

Answer (score 5):

Usually I put these in the const environment file. If you are using angular-cli, this is already provided for you if not you can create your own:

```
export const environment = {  
  production: false,
  api: 'http://localhost:4200/api/'
};
```

You can have multiple environment file, like environment.production.ts, then with angular-cli you would run:

```
ng build --environment=production
```

If you are not using angular-cli, pretty sure you can build your own something similar.

Comment: @ScottMoniz just `environment.api`. Just make sure you import it first

Comment: Yep - figured it out :) Working well! Happy Holidays to you!

Answer (score 0):

```
export class AppSettings {
   public static API_ENDPOINT='http://127.0.0.1:6666/api/';
}
```

And then in the service:

```
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import {Message} from '../models/message';
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {AppSettings} from '../appSettings';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class MessageService {

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getMessages(): Observable<Message[]> {
        return this.http.get(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT+'/messages')
            .map(response => response.json())
            .map((messages: Object[]) => {
                return messages.map(message => this.parseData(message));
            });
    }

    private parseData(data): Message {
        return new Message(data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In `app module` add window object

```
import {provide} from 'angular2/core';
bootstrap([provide(Window, {useValue: window})]);
```

After that you can  access `window` in controller

```
constructor(private window: Window) {
 var hostname = this.window.location.hostname;
}
```

There is no angular 2 specific solution.In angularJS(version 1) we use `$location` service

```
$location.protocol() + "://" + $location.host() + ":" + $location.port();
```

Answer (score -2):

You can create an Interceptor to add the base API URL

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log('Custom Interceptor');

    // Adding serverHostURL to all APIs in Interceptor
    const serverHostURL = 'http://localhost:8080';
    request = request.clone({
      url: serverHostURL + request.url
    });


    return next.handle(request);
  }
```

Above code should do.